# Commission distributes up to 6 levels PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a user database where users can register. A is a Root user. B is a child of A and C is Child Of B. Every user has many child.

Commission distributes different % each level, which assign global variables. My database user table is:

[image]

```
 // referral comissions
$eredm= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT u1.username AS referral1,u2.username AS 
    referral2,u3.username AS referral3,u4.username AS referral4,u5.username 
 AS 
    referral5,u6.username AS referral6,u7.username AS referral7,u8.username 
 AS 
   referral8,u9.username AS referral9,u10.username AS referral10 
   FROM users AS u1 
  LEFT JOIN users As u2 ON u2.sponsorid = u1.username
  LEFT JOIN users As u3 ON u3.sponsorid = u2.username 
  LEFT JOIN users As u4 ON u4.sponsorid = u3.username 
  LEFT JOIN users As u5 ON u5.sponsorid = u4.username 
  LEFT JOIN users As u6 ON u6.sponsorid = u5.username 
  LEFT JOIN users As u7 ON u7.sponsorid = u6.username 
  LEFT JOIN users As u8 ON u8.sponsorid = u7.username
  LEFT JOIN users As u9 ON u9.sponsorid = u8.username 
  LEFT JOIN users As u10 ON u10.sponsorid = u9.username 
    WHERE u1.username='rootusername'");
  $rows= mysqli_fetch_array($eredm);

  $referrer1 = $rows['referral1'];
  $referrer2 = $rows['referral2'];
  $referrer3 = $rows['referral3'];
  $referrer4 = $rows['referral4'];
 $referrer5 = $rows['referral5'];
 $referrer6 = $rows['referral6'];
 $referrer7 = $rows['referral7'];
 $referrer8 = $rows['referral8'];
 $referrer9 = $rows['referral9'];
  $referrer10 = $rows['referral10'];

 $refpc[1]=$refpc1; $refpc[2]=$refpc2; $refpc[3]=$refpc3; $refpc[4]=$refpc4; 
 $refpc[5]=$refpc5; 
 $refpc[6]=$refpc6; $refpc[7]=$refpc7; $refpc[8]=$refpc8; $refpc[9]=$refpc9; 
 $refpc[10]=$refpc10; 

 $cref[1]=$referrer1; $cref[2]=$referrer2; $cref[3]=$referrer3; 
 $cref[4]=$referrer4; $cref[5]=$referrer5; 
 $cref[6]=$referrer6; $cref[7]=$referrer7; $cref[8]=$referrer8; 
 $cref[9]=$referrer9; $cref[10]=$referrer10; 

 $i=1;
  while($i<=$rlevels){

  if (!($cref[$i]=='_')){
$curcomission = ($invest_to_add/100)*$refpc[$i];
$curref = $cref[$i];
$eredm = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE users SET earned=earned+$curcomission 
WHERE username='$curref'");
$ma = date("Y-m-d");
$eredm = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO 
  credits(s_date,s_reason,s_amount,s_user,s_type) VALUES('$ma','Ref. comission 
 from $userid',$curcomission,'$curref',1)") or die(mysql_error());
}
 $i++;
 }
```

The problem is that only  6 level can get commission from the root. It should be distributed only for active member 6 levels up from new member. What can i do? Please help me.

Comment: there is no question here.

Comment: Anybody help me

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be
reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post
code samples of what you have done 
(i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Comment: help with what? you haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: The problem is that only 6 level can get commission from the root. It should be distributed only for active member 6 levels up from new member. What can i do? Please help me.